# How to combine Rails I18n locales, using en, but with es for number.currency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a multi-tenant Rails application supporting three languages: `es`, `en`, and `pt-BR`.

Users can select which language they want, for example, `en`, but if the base account they are accessing is in `es`, although they can switch to `en` we still want to show currency based on the base account: `es.number.currency`. No matter the language a user may pick, they will still see the currency based on the base account.

My initial thought was to dynamically set `I18n.backend.store_translations`:

```rb
around_action :switch_locale

def switch_locale(&action)
  I18n.backend.store_translations(
    user_locale,
    number: {
      currency: I18n.t('number.currency', locale: base_account_locale)
    }
  )
  I18n.with_locale(user_locale, &action)
end
```

But that does not work with threads. In case a user with `en` and a base account with `es`, that would "fix" the problem for the user, but it would also introduce a bug making all base accounts in `en` to see the currency in `es` given that `I18n.backend.store_translations` is not per request.

Another option that seems overly "hacking" is to dynamically create locales, for example, `en-with-currency-es`

```rb
def switch_locale(&action)
  new_combined_locale = "#{user_locale}-with-currency-#{base_account_locale}"

  original_user_locale_translations = I18n.t(user_locale)

  # combine user locale with the base account currency
  original_user_locale_translations = original_user_locale_translations.merge(
    number: {
      currency: I18n.t('number.currency', locale: current_box.locale)
    }
  )

  I18n.backend.store_translations(
    new_combined_locale,
    original_user_locale_translations
  )

  I18n.with_locale(new_combined_locale, &action)
end
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Your option to create dynamically the locales is fine. The goal of Rails is to cover 80% of the use cases, and you seem to be in the 20 remaining percents.

Excepted if you find a gem that would cover your use case (I never saw that until today), I would go the way you showed.

But here is my input:

### In the case you have a JavaScript application

Given you're using a JavaScript framework like React to name one, I would go with a `BootstrapController` that would be called at the loading of the JS app, so that it would provide configuration like routes and so on and the `number.currency` translations in the base account locale, stored locally.

Then, where it's needed, I would load specifically the stored translation rather than asking Rails to give me the translation.

### In the case you're not having a JavaScript application

I would then go with [a `Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) that would embed the hacky logic you've posted, and in the controllers actions where it is required, I would call a method from that concern that would inject the special translations.

To speed a up this case I would go with some caching that would be invalidated after a deployment of the app (I guess, the translations are deployed with the Rails app, so if you change the translations, they'll need to invalidated only at the deployment stage, right?

Comment: I'm worried about the performance of auto-generating locales. Could that cause any problem?

Comment: That's why I talked about caching in the non JavaScript way. In the JavaScript way, you call the bootstrap controller only once, so no perf issues.